# Attributes just disappear when I give a method as parameter

Tags: python, methods

I look for an answer but no one suits to my problem...
I tried to make a Timer which should call a given function every n-ticks, but it doesn't work and when I debugged my object, the attribute `callback_function` that supposed to store the function to call just disappears.

Here is the code:

```
import pygame

class Timer:
    def __init__(self, time, callback_function, repeat=False, how_many=0,
                 infinite=False, *args, **kwargs):
    self.now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    self.time = time
    self.callback_function = callback_function
    self.repeat = repeat
    self.how_many = how_many
    self.infinite = infinite
    self.args = args
    self.kwargs = kwargs
    self.active = True

    def update(self):
        if pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.now >= self.time and self.active:
            self.callback_function(self.args, self.kwargs)

            if((self.how_many == 0 and not self.infinite) or 
               self.repeat == False):
                self.active = False
                return False
            elif not self.infinite:
                self.how_many -= 1

            self.now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            return True
```

More code:

```
import pygame

from api.ActorSprite import ActorSprite
from api.Timer import Timer

class ActorTest(ActorSprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(pygame.image.load("assets/mario.jpg").convert())

        self.add_timer(timer = Timer(2000, self.print_test,repeat=True,how_many=2))

    def draw(self, screen):
        super().draw(screen)
        self.update_timers()

    def print_test(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Hello World!")
```

There is no error message, the function `print_test` is just not called. But when I don't use the super class of `ActorTest` to manage the `Timer`, it works...I don't get it!

These are screenshots from my debugger:

- <[screenshot showing instantiation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJatN.png)>
- <[screenshot showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0nfW.png)>

Comment: "vanish".....??

Comment: The code is not a complete example.

Comment: Could you please edit the question and include the complete error message that you are seeing?

Comment: Does the code as you've posted it in the question look exactly like in your editor or IDE? I suppose the `update` function must be indented one more level, but I'm not sure if it's just an issue with the StackOverflow editor.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is really the cause of your problem, but instead of this:

> ```
> self.callback_function = lambda *args, **kwargs: callback_function(args, kwargs)
> ```

you should simply write

```
self.callback_function = callback_function
```

Comment: I wrote it like that and thought the error could come from there, but nope.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm sorry it was just a bug from my debugger, the problem wasn't there. It works well now, thank you !